# Trying to fix the error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: python, mysql

```
def SignUp(self):
    n=self.lineEdit.text()
    m=self.lineEdit_2.text()
    us= self.lineEdit_4.text()
    pww = self.lineEdit_5.text()
    query=("insert into users(name,matric,username,password), values ('%s,%s,%s,%s)")
    cur.execute(query,(n,m,us,pww))
    cur.commit()
```

This is my coding for Python. I'm using PyQt Designer and MySql. 
I keep getting the error ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', values ('asdasda','asdasdasf','sdafdssa')' at line 1. Pls help

Comment: Typo: Get rid of the quote before `%s`.

Comment: ...and the comma before `values`.

Comment: Thankss :) it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

query=("insert into users(name,matric,username,password), values ('%s,%s,%s,%s)")

should be

**query=("insert into users(name,matric,username,password) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)")**

Comment: please accept it as answer and upvote it.. :)